# Nothing showing when plotting vector tile layer from Arcgis server on MapBox GL JS map

Tags: mapbox, arcgis, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to plot a supplied vector tile layer onto a map using MapBox GL JS. I've followed the [documentation here](https://developers.arcgis.com/mapbox-gl-js/layers/add-a-vector-tile-layer/#add-a-fill-layer) but nothing apart from the basic map is being output and there are no console errors. In the browser's Network tab I can see lots of .pbf requests being returned with data so it would seem that the endpoint is passing data back, but I don't know how to determine what the problem is in plotting that data onto the map.

The code is as follows:

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = '[my access token]';
      const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
        zoom: 6,
        center: [-0.118092, 51.509865]
      });

      map.once("load", () => {
        map.addSource("ncn", {
          type: "vector",
          tiles: [
            "https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/1ZHcUS1lwPTg4ms0/arcgis/rest/services/NCN_Vector_Tile_Package/VectorTileServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.pbf"
          ]
        });

        map.addLayer({
          id: "ncn-lines",
          type: "line",
          source: "ncn",
          "source-layer": "NCN_Vector_Tile_Package",
          "layout": {
            "visibility": "visible"
          },
          'paint': {
            'line-color': 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'
          }
        });
      });
```

I am fairly sure that the `type` should be `line` (rather than `fill`) as the data is supposed to contain route lines rather than vector shapes.

I don't have access to the Arcgis server so can't see how anything is configured at that side. Can anyone suggest what might be wrong here and/or how to debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the value for `source-layer` is not correct - it should be `NCN_2020`. Here's a demo showing it working: https://jsbin.com/xunuhibuki/1/edit?html,output

How do you get that value? I'm not quite sure the best way, but the way I found: add `?f=html` to your vector tile layer like this: https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/1ZHcUS1lwPTg4ms0/arcgis/rest/services/NCN_Vector_Tile_Package/VectorTileServer/?f=html then click "Styles" link at the bottom which gives you an example of how to construct your `map.addLayer()` commands in your mapboxgl code.